# Where do I put a helper function in a Typescript react component?

Tags: reactjs

I just want to make a simple function that does something when a text field input is changed.

I have setup the text field as such:

```
import React from 'react';
import { TextField, Grid } from '@material-ui/core';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/styles';

interface InputWithDynamicHelperTextProps {
  label?: string;
}

const InputWithDynamicHelperText = ({
  label,
}: InputWithDynamicHelperTextProps) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Grid container spacing={3}>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <TextField label={label} variant="outlined" handleChange={this.handleChange}/>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

handleChange (event) {
  console.log("hello");
};

export default InputWithDynamicHelperText;
```

But where ever I put the handleChange function it doesn't work.

Would any know the correct place to put this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include `handleChange` function inside `InputWithDynamicHelperText` like,

```
const InputWithDynamicHelperText = ({
  label
}: InputWithDynamicHelperTextProps) => {
  const handleChange = event => {
    console.log("hello", event.target.value);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <Grid container spacing={3}>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <TextField
            label={`Dynamic Label`}
            onChange={handleChange}
            variant="outlined"
          />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Here you can assign the function name into `onChange` event like,

```
onChange={handleChange}
```

> [**Working Codesandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-picker-custom-text-field-6vt3z)